# UI (XAML) is not updating the properties But propertyChanged triggred in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have been facing a issue in updating the XAML in windows phone 8... the properties are binded in XAML with the viewModel, propertyChange is triggered and it changes the values of the properties. but the property members in XAML are only updated once at the beginning since then it does not update any thing in XAML... Although the properties continue to change in ViewModel.... the properties belong to a LIST of observation collection and finally Observation Collection is binded to LongListSelector

I have changed the binding Mode to "two Way" but useless i have pasted the code below.

Looking forward for help.

ViewModel:

```
    private string _description;
    public string description
    {
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("_description");
        }
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
    }

    private double _progress_bar_Value;
    public double progress_bar_Value
    {
        set
        {
            _progress_bar_Value = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("_progress_bar_Value");
        }
        get
        {
            return _progress_bar_Value; //= ProfileSetting.ProfileTab_DOB;

        }
    }



    private double _Total_Bytes;
    public double Total_Bytes
    {
        set
        {
            _Total_Bytes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("_Total_Bytes");
        }
        get
        {
            return _Total_Bytes;

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

`

```
                                    >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" 
                                    >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"
                                       FontSize="18"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Foreground="White" x:Name="Totalsize"
                                       />
                            <ProgressBar x:Name="Download_progressBar" 
                                         IsIndeterminate="False" 
                                         Maximum="100" 
                                         Height="10" 
                                         Width="400" 
                                         Value="{Binding progress_bar_Value}"
                                         Foreground="White"
                                         />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bytes_received}"
                                       FontSize="18"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       x:Name="Total_received"
                               />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>`
```

Comment: remove the _ The propertyName argument needs to match the property name, not the backing field.

Answer (score 0):

Raise Property Changed on the public property not backing field (as commented by @HighCore)